# What is the correct pattern for splitting a string in javascript, leaving just a-z words

Tags: javascript

I have the next code that was given to me to split up a string into an array.

```
var chk = str.split(/[^a-z']+/i);
```

The problem I'm having with this solution is that if the string has a period in the end, it's being replaced with ","

For example:
If I have the next string: "hi,all-I'm-glad."
The solution above results: "hi,all,I'm,glad," (notice the "," in the end).
I need that the new string will be: "hi,all,I'm,glad"

How can I acheive it ?

Comment: If you had actually tried some of the alternative solutions in your last post, you would have found the answer.

Comment: @JoelLundberg, I've looked into other solution in my last post and none solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for a `.` being the last character and remove it first

```
var str = "hi,all-I'm-glad. that you, can help,me. that-doesn't make any-sense, I know.";
if(str.charAt( str.length-1 ) == ".") {
   str = str.substring(0,str.length-1);
}
var chk = str.split(/[^a-z']+/i);
console.log(chk);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var chk = str.match(/[a-z']+/gi);

console.log(chk);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the last element of your string array returns an empty string and remove that element

```
if (chk[chk.length-1] == "")
{
  chk.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var chk="to.to.".split(/[^a-z']+/i); if(chk[chk.length-1].length==0){chk.pop()}; console.log(chk);
```

To remove the last value of your array using pop if this one is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the pure regex power:

```
"hi,all-I'm-glad. that you, can help,me. that-doesn't make any-sense, I know.".replace(/[\-\.\s]/g, ',').replace(/,{2,}/g, ',').replace(/,$/,'')
```